# The new [0.999] tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

Some one has decided to create a new tag for the whole (0.999) questions, and then tag 13 questions within a short time.

I've left that user a comment regarding this behavior, but I wanted to raise the question whether or not we need that tag at all? Is (0.999) a reasonable tag?

Comment: No. It is not. It is not even correctly typed: the questions to which it is applied generally concerns the repeating $0.\overline{99}$ and not the number $999 / 1000$. It probably should be merged into [tag:number-systems]. But I haven't looked carefully at all 13 to see if there are any exceptions.

Comment: Maybe the little-used [tag:decimal-expansion] is a better merge target.

Comment: @Arthur: I think it might be wise just to nuke the tag and go on. It seems mostly about $0.\bar9=1$. And I mean, how many questions are we going to have on the topic which are not duplicate? Like five or six? All the rest could be reduced back to those and the plethora of answers they have received.

Comment: I think that we do not need this tag. The only use it has is to collect all these questions and, if not burn them, then at least close all but the first as duplicates.

Comment: @Jyrki: Should we also shoot the authors of these questions as well, or perhaps just cut off their fingers would suffice? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Cutting of $0.\bar{9}$ fingers will suffice.

Comment: I think you mean $0.\overline{9}$ *finger*.

Comment: This question needs a $(0.999)$ tag too.

Comment: In response to the concern raised by @WillieWong I suggest we change the tag to (1.000).

Comment: @ArthurFischer: That sounds fine. One of us should go ahead and do the merge.

Comment: @Willie, Arthur: Please post your action as an answer, so I can accept it afterwards.

Comment: @Asaf: merging is much easier to do for moderators; so whenever possible I prefer to find an appropriate tag to merge into.

Comment: @Willie: I yearn for the days where moderators could have just deleted a tag...

Comment: Someone created a [real-numbers] tag, maybe that would fit? (I am thinking of the discussion in Kelley's topology..)

Comment: @Willie: Sure, but do we wanna keep that one?

Comment: @WillieWong, when I attempted to create the tag "0.999..." the dots got deleted and the tag "0.999" was created instead. The questions mostly concern the issue why the string "0.999..." evaluates to 1. In other words, the string itself is the issue and not the real number it evaluates to. Thus renaming it "1.000" is not too informative. Having such a tag will make future duplications on this subject easier to spot.

Comment: @user72694: The point is that there are generally two or three non-isomorphic questions, and those were asked and are easy to find.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I don't see why not. There are tags on complex- and rational- numbers.

Comment: @Willie: And those are not that great either. For the natural numbers... maaaybe it's fine because those are usually taken in a whole other context of number theory or logic or whatnot. But rational, real and complex numbers... are just there for analysis. :-)

Comment: @user72694: see [Jyrki's comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11734/the-new-0-999-tag?noredirect=1#comment45641_11734). I somehow doubt users would be so kind as to tag their questions 0.999 is it becomes clear that that tag just collects duplicates. Much easier to just write up a canonical answer on the subject and tag it as (faq), and close all trivial permutations of it as duplicate.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen's suggestion to "close all but the first as duplicates" does not do justice to this group of questions. For example, [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281492/about-0-999-1) addresses hyperreal interpretations of an infinite string of 9s that fall infinitesimally short of 1. Note that the ensuing discussion was refreshingly calm and did *not* include finger chopping proposals.

Comment: @user72694: This is why I said that the majority of the questions are isomorphic to a small handful of questions which are easy to find. I do agree there are a few other interesting questions, but not enough to merit a whole dedicated tag.

Comment: After looking at these comments I thought "who said that mathematicians do not make jokes?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In view of the discussion and vote counts above, I have merged (0.999) into [decimal-expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decimal-expansion). The choice of target tag is due to

1. Arthur's much upvoted comment [above](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11734/the-new-0-999-tag?cb=1#comment45618_11734).
2. 10 of the 13 questions using the tag already uses [decimal-expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decimal-expansion), so this is the minimally disruptive way of removing the tag.

Answer (score 14):

No way.  This is a micro-interest tag.   It is not worthy of a category on this forum. We all know that some base expansions are just not unique. We all get over this.

Comment: An optimist, are you?

Comment: When I see a great pile of horse-dung, I keep digging until I find the pony.

Answer (score 3):

The only advantage I see to having a tag like this is that I can add it to my 'ignored tags' list.